# File::Tail::Select what is the @pending behaviour

Tags: perl, filehandle

```
foreach my $subfile(glob "*:*")

    {
            print "opening $subfile\n";
            push(@files,File::Tail->new(name=>"$subfile",debug=>$debug));
    }
    while (1)
    {
            ($nfound,$timeleft,@pending)= File::Tail::select(undef,undef,undef,$timeout,@files);
            unless ($nfound)
            {
               # timeout - do something else here, if you need to
            }
            else
            {
                    foreach (@pending)
                    {
                            print $_->{"input"}." (".localtime(time).") ".$_-> read;
                    }
            }
    }
```

what is the @pending behavior?if the result display as below...

```
TCP:34628-80 (Wed Mar 30 01:49:57 2011) 03/30-01:49:50.607858 119.40.116.196:80 -> 192.168.242.133:34628
TCP:34628-80 (Wed Mar 30 01:49:57 2011) TCP TTL:128 TOS:0x0 ID:34869 IpLen:20 DgmLen:40
TCP:34629-80 (Wed Mar 30 01:49:57 2011) 03/30-01:49:51.309716 119.40.116.196:80 -> 192.168.242.133:34629
UDP:41415-53 (Wed Mar 30 01:49:57 2011) 03/30-01:49:47.220999 192.168.242.2:53 -> 192.168.242.133:41415
UDP:44705-53 (Wed Mar 30 01:49:57 2011) 03/30-01:49:47.427011 192.168.242.2:53 -> 192.168.242.133:44705
UDP:50539-53 (Wed Mar 30 01:49:57 2011) 03/30-01:49:47.213455 192.168.242.2:53 -> 192.168.242.133:50539
TCP:34628-80 (Wed Mar 30 01:49:57 2011) ***AP**F Seq: 0x2F3E700A  Ack: 0x2359814F  Win: 0xFAF0  TcpLen: 20
TCP:34629-80 (Wed Mar 30 01:49:57 2011) TCP TTL:128 TOS:0x0 ID:34871 IpLen:20 DgmLen:40
UDP:41415-53 (Wed Mar 30 01:49:57 2011) UDP TTL:128 TOS:0x0 ID:34859 IpLen:20 DgmLen:65
UDP:44705-53 (Wed Mar 30 01:49:57 2011) UDP TTL:128 TOS:0x0 ID:34861 IpLen:20 DgmLen:153
UDP:50539-53 (Wed Mar 30 01:49:57 2011) UDP TTL:128 TOS:0x0 ID:34857 IpLen:20 DgmLen:179
TCP:34628-80 (Wed Mar 30 01:49:57 2011) =+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+
TCP:34629-80 (Wed Mar 30 01:49:57 2011) ***AP**F Seq: 0x9D70418  Ack: 0x248089DB  Win: 0xFAF0  TcpLen: 20
UDP:41415-53 (Wed Mar 30 01:49:57 2011) Len: 37
UDP:44705-53 (Wed Mar 30 01:49:57 2011) Len: 125
UDP:50539-53 (Wed Mar 30 01:49:57 2011) Len: 151
TCP:34628-80 (Wed Mar 30 01:49:57 2011) 
TCP:34629-80 (Wed Mar 30 01:49:57 2011) =+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+
```

isn't that @pending will store the data line by line?how do i modify the code to only retrieve the IP address?In my opinion i think i can use split() to break the line into word by word..so anyone can give me some example about it

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions would be the easiest way to get the IP address:

```
if (/([.\d]+):\d -> ([.\d]+):\d/) {
     # ipaddress 1 will be in $1, and ip address 2 will be in $2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## !/usr/local/bin/perl

use File::Tail;

chdir( "/var/log/snort");

foreach my $fol(glob "*.*.*.*")
{

```
    print "Opening $fol\n";

    chdir("/var/log/snort/$fol");

    foreach my $subfile(glob "*:*")
    {

            print "opening $subfile\n";

            push(@files,File::Tail->new(name=>"$subfile",debug=>$debug));
    }

    while (1)
    {
            ($nfound,$timeleft,@pending)= File::Tail::select(undef,undef,undef,$timeout,@files);
            unless ($nfound)
            {
                    print "Nothing to print \n";
            }
            else
```

foreach (@pending)
                        {
                               if (/([.\d]+):\d -> ([.\d]+):\d/)
                                {

```
                                    print $_->{"input"}." (".localtime(time).") ".$2 -> read;
                                                                  }
                    }
            }
    }
```

}
hey guy i working out like this...isn't this correct?it seem like nothing to print out